# Can I setup a pir sensor to turn on and off 2 monitors on raspberry pi4?

Tags: raspbian-buster

I am building a raspberry pi 4 system with 2 monitors and would like to know how to turn on and off the 2 monitors with a pir sensor. I am quite a noobie with Raspberry pi so would require a clear and simple tutorial on how to achieve this if it's possible.

Comment: Two real options for monitor control CEC and power - power would involve adding a remote controlled power socket and controlling that from the Pi, CEC -  look at https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/raspberry-pi-power-on-off-tv-connected.html and try the power commands.  Then come back and explain a bit more about how you want things to work and what you have.

Comment: [Read first](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=turn+monitor+on+raspberry+pi&ia=web) - ask questions later.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is possible.

I currently have a a pi that controls a 5V80A power supply via a solid state relay. So it is quite similar to what you're trying to accomplish, if you're trying to simply toggle to power directly.

All you would have to do if create a basic python script that you have set to run as a daemon, i.e. `nohup python3 foobar.py &`. The script would be checking the state of the PIR sensor. Once triggered it can then send the signal to toggle the state of the monitors directly via a GPIO pin connected to the monitor's relay.